# How to define an array of structs return type in ethers.js ABI

Tags: ethers.js, decentralized-applications

Currently I got this abi:

```js
const stakingAbi = [
    'function getStakes(address user) external view returns (Stake[] memory)',
    'function stake7Days(uint128 _amount) external whenNotPaused',
    'function stake14Days(uint128 _amount) external whenNotPaused',
    'function stake30Days(uint128 _amount) external whenNotPaused',
    'function stake90Days(uint128 _amount) external whenNotPaused'
]
```

The `Stake` struct looks like this:

```
struct Stake {
    uint16 bonusPercentage;
    uint40 unlockTimestamp;
    uint128 amount;
    bool withdrawn;
}
```

Currently the getStakes function doesn't work because Ethers doesn't know what `Stake[]` is, how do I define this in the ABI?

Comment: Does it throw error?! It should return list of Object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying structs in the human-readable ABI format is still not supported in ethers.js. See https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/315

You would need to use the JSON ABI format: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/#abi-formats--solidity

Alternatively, you work around it by returning an array of tuples:

```
function getStakes(address user) external view returns (tuple(uint16 bonusPercentage, uint40 unlockTimestamp, uint128 amount, bool withdrawn)[] memory)
```

Or tuple of arrays:

```
function getStakes(address user) external view returns (uint16[] memory, uint40[] memory, uint128[] memory, bool[] memory)
```